# Why can we not store all hash results in a database and look them up?

Tags: hash

When somebody wants to find out a password by using its hash, he can use for example John the Ripper.

Then he runs the application for days or weeks or years, hoping to somewhen guess the right result.

All the negatives (not working attempts) are simply discarded.

Why do we not store them in a sorted database?
For example:

```
Hash              Text               Method 
AED8234872343     somestring         PKZIP
AED8234872346     someotherstring    PKZIP
```

etc.

Then, next time we need to look up for example "AED8234872343", we don't have to run all the calculations again. Instead, we can use just a SQL search like this:

```
SELECT text FROM hashes WHERE hash = 'AED8234872343' AND method = 'PKZIP'
```

Would that not work?
Of course, we could split the database into many smaller database, but it would still be faster to look it up like this than to try to all texts again, right?

Thank you!

Comment: You may be interested in Rainbow Tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, this is possible, but it presumes that we have way more storage space than we have in practice.

SHA-256 produces results, which are 256 bits long. This in turn means there are 2^256 different hashes possible. In decimal, that would be 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936 different hashes.

If we presume, that each entry would consist of only one byte (which it can't since the password is longer than one byte), that would be 1.158×10^77 bytes. This is *magnitudes* more data than every hard drive in the world could store.

In fact, if all of humanity had done nothing but produce 1 PB harddrives for all of human history, then we wouldn't even come close to having the capacity of storing all hashes. It is simply infeasible. There are way too many hashes out there to store them all.

#### What about other look-up tables?

There are indeed projects out there to store "common" hashes. For example, if I search for `008c70392e3abfbd0fa47bbc2ed96aa99bd49e159727fcba0f2e6abeb3a9d601` online, I will get the plaintext to this hash immediately. This makes sense, because back in the day, many providers stored passwords as unsalted hashes.

For this reason, salts (small, random strings) were appended to passwords, so that building a database of even common passwords plus salts becomes infeasible. Appending just 8 random bytes to any password will make storing just the hashes for `Password123` impossible. Of course, that means the provider has to store the salt for each individual user, but that's not a big deal. Even at a billion accounts, that just means 8 GB used for salts.

So just hashing a list of "common passwords" and storing those makes sense. Hashing a list of all possible passwords is infeasible.

Comment: You touched on it, but it would be worth mentioning that all good password hashes include a salt, and the point of the salt is to make storing hashes even less useful.

Comment: @user10489 Yeah, that's true. I'll include it.